# How to add RecyclerView in a Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Currently, I am trying to implement `RecyclerView` inside of `Fragment` but I cannot find a way to display it.

Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
package com.example

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.projectdrivemark.R
import com.example.projectdrivemark.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.recyclerView.MockDatabase.Companion.createMockData
import com.example.recyclerView.PostAdapter
import com.example.recyclerView.RecyclerViewFragment
import com.example.tempConverter.TempConverterFragment
import com.example.uploaderView.UploaderFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PostAdapter.OnPostClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    val dummyList = createMockData()
    val adapter = PostAdapter(dummyList, this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        title = "First Kotlin App"
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val recyclerView = RecyclerViewFragment()
        val tempConverterView = TempConverterFragment()
//        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val uploaderView = UploaderFragment(this)
        setFragmentView(recyclerView)

        binding.bottomNavBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.listView ->  setFragmentView(recyclerView)
                R.id.tempConverterView -> setFragmentView(tempConverterView)
                R.id.videoUploaderView -> setFragmentView(uploaderView)
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun setFragmentView(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.main_fragment_view, fragment)
            //Will return to previous page when tap "Back Button" on the phone
            addToBackStack(null)
            commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onEditPost(position: Int){
        val clickedPost = dummyList[position]
        clickedPost.title = "Updated title"
        clickedPost.body = "Updated body"
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    override fun onDeletePost(position: Int) {
        dummyList.removeAt(position)
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

    fun celsiusFunction(view: View) {
        val tempConverter = TempConverterFragment()
        tempConverter.celsiusFunction(view)
    }

    fun farenheitFunction(view: View){
       val fahrenheitConverter = TempConverterFragment()
        fahrenheitConverter.farenheitFunction(view)
    }
}
```

Here is my `RecyclerFragment`:

```
package com.example.recyclerView

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.MainActivity
import com.example.projectdrivemark.R

class RecyclerViewFragment: Fragment() {
    var adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>? = null
    var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)
        return binding
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.apply{
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = PostAdapter(dummyData = ArrayList<Post>(), MainActivity())
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `PostAdapter` code:

```
package com.example.recyclerView

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.MainActivity
import com.example.projectdrivemark.R

class PostAdapter(val dummyData: ArrayList<Post>, val myListener: MainActivity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>() {

    inner class PostViewHolder(postView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(postView), View.OnClickListener{
        val iconImage: ImageView = postView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_view)
        val title: TextView = postView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        val body: TextView = postView.findViewById(R.id.body)
        val deleteIcon: ImageView = postView.findViewById(R.id.delete_post_image)
        val editIcon: ImageView = postView.findViewById(R.id.edit_post_image)

        init {
            deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(this)
            editIcon.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?){
            val position = adapterPosition
            if(v?.id == editIcon.id){
                myListener.onEditPost(position)
            }else{
                myListener.onDeletePost(position)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
        val postView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.post, parent, false)
        return PostViewHolder(postView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentPost = dummyData[position]
        holder.iconImage.setImageResource(currentPost.image)
        holder.title.text = currentPost.title
        holder.body.text = currentPost.body
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dummyData.size
    }

    interface OnPostClickListener{

        fun onEditPost(position: Int)
        fun onDeletePost(position: Int)
    }
}
```

If anyone saw something I miss, please do tell me because I am stuck at how to display the `RecyclerView`. Any help would be appreciate.

Edit:

Here is my `MockDatabase`:

```
package com.example.recyclerView

import com.example.projectdrivemark.R

class MockDatabase {
    companion object{
        fun createMockData(): ArrayList<Post>{
            val list = ArrayList<Post>()
            for(i in 0 until 20){
                val imageToSelect = when (i % 3){
                    0 -> R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_balance
                    1 -> R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_circle
                    2 ->R.drawable.ic_baseline_ac_unit
                    else -> R.drawable.ic_baseline_access_alarms
                }
                list.add(
                        Post(
                            imageToSelect,
                            title = "Title post of $i",
                            body = "Title post of $i"
                        )
                )
            }
            return list
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Layout_list` xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleViewMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if RecyclerView root and only element in `fragment_list` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I am still new to kotlin.

Comment: please paste your fragment_list.xml also

Comment: can you please post your XML's as well? I guess the recycler view is just a layout not literally recycler view. I haven't worked in Kotlin. But one of the procedures is. 1. in your layout add a recycler view. Give an id to it. Now in the java class initialize that view by using findviewbyid. Then create one adapter, pass layout manager, then set the adapter.

Comment: @sonu kumar prashant. Alright I understand now what you mean by initialize the view from the answer. I have seen my mistake. Thank you for telling me the procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast `view` to `RecyclerView` to access `RecyclerView` properties inside apply, also you cannot create instances of `Activity` by yourself,
`MainActivity()` is wrong and won't work, instead use `requireActivity()` which will provide context of `Activity` to which `Fragment` is attached to

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    view.findViewbyId<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycleViewMain).apply{
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
        adapter = PostAdapter(dummyData = ArrayList<Post>(), requireActivity() as OnPostClickListener)
    }
}
```

Also, as @Necronet mentioned, add some mock data to see if it is actually rendering.

**UPDATE**

Instead of passing `MainActivity` to `Adapter`, pass `OnPostClickListener`

```
adapter = PostAdapter(dummyData = ArrayList<Post>(), requireActivity() as OnPostClickListener)
```

**Adapter**

```
class PostAdapter(val dummyData: ArrayList<Post>, val myListener: OnPostClickListener) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder>(){
   // you can use myListener to call methods
}
```

Comment: I have updated the post and follow both of the answer. When I cas view as RecyclerView it give me an error say that it cannot cast as that type. And then, I have add the Mock Data in the parameters but it say the adapter is not attached.

Comment: updated answer to get reference of `RecyclerView`

Comment: It worked. But I want to ask, as you seen in my MainActivity, I have 2 function that is belong to recyclerView. One is EditPost and DeletePost function. How to call them in RecyclerView Fragment?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple you are passing empty `dummyData` try using `createMockData()` instead. Also as a **rule of thumb** in Android, never ever instatiate an Activity yourself, if you need the reference from within a fragment you can use `getActivity()` method. So this:

`adapter = PostAdapter(dummyData = ArrayList<Post>(), MainActivity())`

Should be:

`adapter = PostAdapter(dummyData = createMockData(), getActivity() as MainActivity)`