# RecyclerView not showing up in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a RecyclerView to a fragment, but without success. I have followed [this guide](https://medium.com/swlh/how-data-binding-helps-you-when-working-with-edittext-inside-recyclerview-543a1eb5f2cc), but in there the RecyclerView is added to MainActivity, so I tried to adapt it. However, I cannot get the RecyclerView to show up.

I have already looked at similar questions, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66236693/how-to-add-recyclerview-in-a-fragment).

Here is the `fragment_add_recipe.xml` where the RecyclerView should appear:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddRecipeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/recipe_name_text_input_layout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/recipe_name_text_input"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/recipe_name_hint"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/ingredient_row_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:itemCount="5"
            tools:listitem="@layout/ingredient_row_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipe_name_text_input_layout"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save_recipe_button"
            android:layout_width="150sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:text="Save"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ingredient_row_recycler_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

`AddRecipeFragment.kt`:

```
package com.example.recipy

import CustomAdapter

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.recipy.databinding.FragmentAddRecipeBinding


class AddRecipeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAddRecipeBinding? = null

//    For the ingredient row
    private val ingredientList : ArrayList<IngredientRowViewModel> = ArrayList()
    private lateinit var customAdapter : CustomAdapter

    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the Fragment layout
        _binding = FragmentAddRecipeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        setAdapter()

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setAdapter(){
        customAdapter = CustomAdapter(ingredientList)
        binding.ingredientRowRecyclerView.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            adapter = customAdapter
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Make button save the recipe in the SQL db
        binding.saveRecipeButton.setOnClickListener{
//            Some code for SQL connection here
        }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

The `IngredientRowViewModel.kt`:

```
package com.example.recipy

data class IngredientRowViewModel(var ingredient: String) {

}
```

The `CustomAdapter.kt`:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.recipy.IngredientRowViewModel
import com.example.recipy.R
import com.example.recipy.databinding.IngredientRowViewBinding

class CustomAdapter(private val ingredientList: ArrayList<IngredientRowViewModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.IngredientRowViewHolder>() {

    inner class IngredientRowViewHolder(private val binding : IngredientRowViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(ingredient : IngredientRowViewModel){
            binding.ingredient = ingredient
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IngredientRowViewHolder =
        IngredientRowViewHolder(IngredientRowViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IngredientRowViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(ingredientList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ingredientList.size
    }
}
```

and finally `ingredient_row_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="ingredient"
            type="com.example.recipy.IngredientRowViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/ingredient_name_text_input_layout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/ingredient_name_text_input"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/ingredient_name_hint"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: after you assign the adapter to the recyclerView.adapter property, call notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: @Chris could you please be more explicit? where should I add it?

Comment: Add `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` under `adapter = customAdapter`. Calling notifyDataSetChanged() will tell the recyclerView that adapter data has changed and recycler will invalidate itself.

Comment: @Miroslav this still does not work

Comment: @gitcanzo Oh sorry, i see now. Your data list is empty, recyclerView is not visible because there is nothing to show yet. Add some items to the list and you will see. Your code is correct.

Comment: @Miroslav but my list should be empty. The recyclerView contains an EditText where the user should then input text

Comment: @gitcanzo But this isn't correct. RecyclerView is working only with the adapter and showing items that adapter provides. Your list is empty, so recyclerView has nothing to show, that's it, this is how RecyclerView works. In the tutorial you mentioned you can see that list is populated on button click. After you add some item to the list and notify adapter about the change, Recycler will show it.

Comment: But what shall I do then? I want to create a row where the user can input the ingredient. By the press of a button (to be added) the use can then add a new ingredient row. I tried to adapt this guide where they use edittext with RecyclerView:
https://medium.com/swlh/how-data-binding-helps-you-when-working-with-edittext-inside-recyclerview-543a1eb5f2cc

Comment: Sorry I posted the same article again :) But in there they try to so something similar, no? Just a list of empty EditText fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code a little, As i mentioned earlier in the comments, you have to add some items to the list if you want to see it. You can add button for adding items or you can go with fixed size list.

**fragment_add_receipe.xml**

Add new button for adding ingredients into your list. If you don't need this and want fixed count list, just create the list with empty items, for instance like this:

```
//This will show 5 empty text inputs in the recyclerView
private val ingredientList: ArrayList<IngredientRowViewModel> = arrayListOf(
    IngredientRowViewModel(""),
    IngredientRowViewModel(""),
    IngredientRowViewModel(""),
    IngredientRowViewModel(""),
    IngredientRowViewModel(""),
)
```

fragment_add_receipe.xml with new button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AddRecipeFragment">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/recipe_name_text_input_layout"
        
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/recipe_name_text_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Receipe name"
            android:inputType="text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ingredient_row_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recipe_name_text_input_layout"
        tools:itemCount="5"
        tools:listitem="@layout/ingredient_row_view" />

    <!-- Add new button so you can add ingredients into your list -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addIngredient"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:text="Add Ingredient"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ingredient_row_recycler_view" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_recipe_button"
        android:layout_width="150sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addIngredient" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**AddRecipeFragment.kt**

set `onClickListener` to the addIngredient `Button` and notify your adapter when adding new ingredients. After you add it, `RecyclerView` will show one item (or more) with empty `TextField`.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    binding.addIngredient.setOnClickListener {
        //add new ingredient with empty name into your list so your item will be shown
        ingredientList.add(IngredientRowViewModel(ingredient = ""))
        //Use notifyItemInserted instead of notifyDataSetChanged for better performance
        if (ingredientList.size == 0)
            customAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0)
        else
            customAdapter.notifyItemInserted(ingredientList.size - 1)
    }

    ...

}
```

**ingredient_row_view.xml**

This is just optional, you have `android:layout_height="match_parent"` which means single item would use to much space and you have to scroll in order to see second item, you should change it to `wrap_content`.

**Suggestions**

- Follow the [tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/how-data-binding-helps-you-when-working-with-edittext-inside-recyclerview-543a1eb5f2cc) you mentioned, it's all written in there.
- Check the basics of [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview) and how it works. I just have feeling that you struggle with understanding it.

Comment: Many thanks! How do I update the data in the array based on the input into the editText? Right now, if I write something in the ingredient editText and then do `println(ingredientList)`, I get an array filled with (ingredient="")

Comment: @gitcanzo Yes, it's because you have to set text from the input into your class somehow. You can try `binding.ingredientNameTextInput.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ -> ingredient.ingredient = text.toString() }` in your `IngredientRowViewHolder.onBind`.